# How can I find all tables cells which only contain a non breaking space with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I need to only find the cells in the table which contain `&nbsp;` using jQuery.

```
 <table>
      <tr>
           <td>&nbsp;</td>
           <td>Something</td>
           <td>something else</td>
           <td>&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick guess, maybe a better way

updated  - thanks to Tomalak

```
var x = $('table tr td').filter( function(){
     return $(this).text() == String.fromCharCode(160); 
})
```

Comment: And, I think you should use $(this).text().

Comment: based off of this I found td:contains('" + String.fromCharCode(160) + "') to also work

Comment: Just to point out an alternative way of matching, that is more general:  / /.test(this.innerHTML);

Comment: And when I recently needed to do something similar, I found there was often other white space, or nothing at all, so I needed to match like this:  
/^\s* \s*$|^$/.test(this.innerHTML);